# Ember.js - How can I save data to session from authenticator?

Tags: session, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have tried doing this.get('session') but it gives me nothing.

I want to save data to my session

I only seem to get the information I need from the authenticator but can't seem to be able to pass it around. (Tried a couple of methods suggested on SO but none seem to be able to work from the autheticator)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
  import Torii from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/torii';

  const { service } = Ember.inject;

  export default Torii.extend({
    torii: service('torii'),
    authenticate(options) {
      return this._super(options).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  });
```

Caller of the autheticator (Is the info I need accessible from here already?)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    actions: {
      authenticateSession() {
        this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:torii', 'google-token');
      },
      invalidateSession() {
        this.get('session').invalidate();
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your authenticator's `authenticate` method does not resolve with anything. Change it to

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Torii from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/torii';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Torii.extend({
  torii: service('torii'),
  authenticate(options) {
    return this._super(options).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

to have all attributes in `data` available via the session's `data.authenticated` property, e.g. `this.get('session.data.authenticated.token')`.

Of course in this case you can just remove the overridden `authenticate` method completely if you don't need the logging.