# Ember-Simple-Auth: Authenticated data not accessbile on didTransistion or AfterRender

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

When attempting to access authenticated information `console.log(this.get('session.data.authenticated.userEmail')) => undefined`  from the controller or route it never seems to work when off of events like `didTransition` or `afterRender`. But is accessible on button click actions. Is there some event i’m missing (Like some afterAuth) for the token to be accessible? I’ve been stuck on this for weeks and have just been avoiding it.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
   model() {
      return this.store.createRecord('user');
    },
    actions{
      didTransition: function (){
       Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function () {

            console.log(this.get('session.data.authenticated.userEmail') //returns undefined (Works fine off button clicks)
          })

      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share the route's full source.

Comment: @marcoow updated the post

Comment: What's the value of `this.get('session.data')`?

Comment: @marcoow It's really weird when I console log too my browser it shows authenticated.userEmail . But when I try to get that info as is using the code shown I get undefined

Comment: put a breakpoint at the line and check what the value of `this.get('session.data')` is when it stops there.

Comment: @marcoow basically just a authenticated object with no info. I tried all the functions it had to offer. But nothing was of use

Comment: Which authenticator are you using?

Comment: @marcoow torii using a google api token. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262515/ember-js-how-can-i-save-data-to-session-from-authenticator . Took your suggestion and just removed that override of authenticate